# How to open Powershell with python to it's default location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, directory, assistant

I am trying to make a digital assistant that can open all apps. When I open the PowerShell the directory is set to where the python script is located. I all ready know how to open the command line to the right folder I just need the PowerShell.

What I'm using

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7.9
- Os module
- Thonny ide 3.3.6

What im trying to do is open PowerShell to

```
C:\Users\MyUsername>
```

What I've tried
I use the command 'get-StartApps' in the Powershell to get all the app ids

This is what I've tried to use to open the PowerShell

```
import os
os.system('start Powershell ')

os.startfile(r'C//Users//'+str(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"))+'//AppData//Roaming//Microsoft//Windows//Start Menu//Programs//Windows PowerShell//Windows PowerShell.lnk')
```

I am unsure if app ids are the same on all computer so I will just give a example

```
import os
os.system('start explorer shell:appsfolder\{Id number}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe')
```

Just opens the file explorer but work to open other apps.

Also I would like this to work on all machines to so if you know how please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.system('start /D'+ str(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"))+' powershell')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
os.system('start /D "C:/Users" powershell')
```

The /D switch for the start command sets the path that powershell opens in.

Comment: It needs to have the username "C:/Users/username" of the current user

Comment: ok i got it. I used os.system('start /D'+ str(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"))+' powershell') thanks you for your help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start

Comment: Also, you can just do `os.system('start /D "%USERPROFILE%" powershell')`.